# Internet failover on Cisco ASA 5500 series Primary ISP is on DHCP address and so is backup. Always defaults to backup

Tags: cisco, dhcp, cisco-asa, multi-homed

I had SLA MONITOR setup on my ASA and working fine for months. All traffic was routing through my primary connection. I rebooted my ASA after a firmware upgrade.

When it came back, it would always default to the backup line.
I disconnected the backup line and then all traffic would use the primary line after about 5 seconds.

The moment I connect the backup line, within 5 seconds, all traffic would be routed through that.

- Primary line is on dhcp with `ip address dhcp setroute` with gateway as ISP router
- Secondary line is natted on 192.168.1.200, gateway is natted 192.168.1.1 (mobile router) which has a gateway of ISP router, so i have a double NAT situation there, but it works.

Firmware 9.14(4)23

The gateway of last resort is the gateway on my primary line.

Any ideas how to fix, as I can only find docs for static IPs on outside interfaces, and not with DHCP

Comment: Please edit your question to include your (sanitized) configuration.  Otherwise, we're just guessing.  This question might be better asked on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).